# Heatmap for one column of data in R

Tags: r

Now I have a column of data, which is over 500 rows.

```
#example
df <- data.frame(
  City = c("New York", "LA", "DC", "Boston", "Chicago"),
  Data = c(780, 982, 111, 893, 989)
```

I want to build a heatmap but i only have one variable, which is City.
Can I split this column into multiple columns and create the heatmap.

I am new to R and I can't find any answers online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Heat maps usually involve a quantitative variable broken down by pairs of categorical or ordinal variables. This sounds more like you just want a table of counts by city?

Comment: Nope I have over 500+ cities. No repeated cities.

Comment: I guess I don't understand then... no graphic is going to look good with 500 cells. Plus it's more confusing to assign colors to them and then have the reader look at a key instead of just listing the numbers....

Comment: This isn't the approach I prefer but I was told to do so .. :(

Comment: I was told to have a heatmap of 5 rows. each row contains 100 cities. So each box would present a city...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to duplicate the single column with cbind and plot...

```
library(gplots)
df <- data.frame(
  City = c("New York", "LA", "DC", "Boston", "Chicago"),
  Data = c(780, 982, 111, 893, 989)
)

heatmap.2(cbind(df$Data, df$Data), trace="n", Colv = NA, 
          dendrogram = "row", labCol = "", labRow = df$City, cexRow = 0.75)
```

[image]

### An exmample of wrapping the data to 5x2 (or 100)

Note that I turned of the dendrograms completely as any ordering would be meaningless.

```
heatmap.2(matrix(df$Data, ncol = 2), trace="n", Colv = FALSE, Rowv=FALSE,
      cellnote = matrix(df$City, ncol = 2), notecol = 1, scale = "none",
      dendrogram = "none", labCol = "", labRow = "", cexRow = 0.75)
```

[image]

`labRow`: sets row labels for (use `""` for no label)
`cellnote`: sets the cell label (delete this parameter if you do want cell labels)
`col`: sets the color palette. My suggestion is to use a pre-defined palette from `colorspace`, `RColorBrewer` or `colorRamps`.
Some suggestions:

```
col=col=colorspace::sequential_hcl(15)
col=col=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "BuGn"
col=colorRamps::ygobb(25)
```

[See this link](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/%7Efrazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) for more on color palettes in R

Comment: That's a neat trick but this still seems like a super weird choice for how to display this kind of data.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I am looking for!!!!!!! Just a few questions, how to remove the label? And how change the color?