# How to best represent a matrix with one column of data with a heatmap

Tags: r, graphics, heatmap

I am used to making heatmaps in a particular manner. I have included a toy example and a generic code of how I make heatmaps.

```
>library(reshape2)
>library(gplots)
>library(RColorBrewer)

>dput(head(X))
structure(c(1.1, 0.4, 2.1, 2.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.7, 2.4, 2.7), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("GeneA", "GeneB", "GeneC"), c("sample1", 
"sample2", "sample3")))

>hr <- hclust(as.dist(1-cor(t(X), method = "pearson")) ,method= "average")
>mycl <- cutree(hr, h=max(hr$height/1.3))

>clusterCols <- rainbow(length(unique(mycl)))
>myClusterSideBar <- clusterCols[mycl]
>myheatcol <- rev(redblue(75))

>heatmap.2(X, main="RBP enrichment profiles", Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr), Colv = NULL, dendrogram="row",scale="row", col=myheatcol, density.info="none", trace="none", RowSideColors= myClusterSideBar) -> HM
```

This works well for matrix's with multiple rows and columns but I have a matrix with only one column of data. Is there a method of altering this code to produce a similar plot.

A small sample of the data in question is below.

```
> dput(head(mydata))
structure(c(21.1545836987, -1.6564670831, -2.8577854708, -2.2236733666, 
2.0775473007, 3.0734379897), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("LENG1.1", "Dec-01", "Mar-02", "A1CF", "AADACL2-AS1", "AANAT"
    ), "Log2FC"))
```

Can I turn this data into a heatmap? Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Check a solution to a related question [Heatmap for one column of data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768528/heatmap-for-one-column-of-data-in-r).

Comment: This solution helped. Thank you !